# Concatenate list of numpy 3d tensors into one 4d tensor?

Tags: numpy, 3d, tensor, 4d

I have list of 3d numpy arrays of different shapes, e.g. (128, 128, 3). Now I want to combine all those arrays into one single 4d tensor which looks like (N, ?, ?, ?), where N is the number of 3d arrays. How do I achieve this with numpy?

Comment: what do you mean by different shapes?  You only give one.

Comment: `concatenate` requires that all arrays share a shape with the exception of the axis of concatenation.  You can't just stack random shapes together.

Comment: Why do you want to this? What problem do you actually want to solve? Maybe there is a better approach for you problem